# Can't show the element when its class or id contains dots

Tags: javascript, jquery

I must have class which contains dots, but then jQuery doesn't work. What should I do?
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/9KYmx/

```
<div style="display: none" class="dfv.png">
    text
</div>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dfv.png').show();
})
```

P.S. ID also doesn't work.

Comment: It's invalid for your class to contain dots in it's name.  You'd be better of writing valid HTML/CSS to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your selector is constant, you have to escape dots with backslash (`\`), So you should do:

```
$('.dfv\\.png').show();
```

But, a more general solution is to auto-escape special characters.
You could escape all special characters with the [Ian McKellar's escape plugin](http://ianloic.com/2009/12/27/jquery-selector-escaping/), the code is short:

```
//Just copy and paste this 
(function() {
escape_re = /[#;&,\.\+\*~':"!\^\$\[\]\(\)=>|\/\\]/;
jQuery.escape = function jQuery$escape(s) {
  var left = s.split(escape_re, 1)[0];
  if (left == s) return s;
  return left + '\\' + 
    s.substr(left.length, 1) + 
    jQuery.escape(s.substr(left.length+1));
}
})();
```

So you do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var your_selector = "dfv.png"; //your_selector can be variable
    $("."+$.escape(your_selector)).show();
});
```

Hope this helps.
Cheers

Comment: Thaks a lot! You too. Cheers, from La Paz, Bolivia

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape them. From [the manual:](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

```
If you wish to use any of the meta-characters 
( such as !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~ ) as a 
literal part of a name, you must escape the character 
with two backslashes: \\. For example, if you have an 
element with id="foo.bar", 
you can use the selector $("#foo\\.bar").
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `.`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dfv\\.png').show();
})
```

Comment: Class are defined, I can't escape. Is it possible in jQuery to use smth like in php str_replace? Then I would replace dot with \.

Comment: Class is given. Then I put it in array like `info['id']` and it is equal `dfv.png`. Then I need to make it `dfv\\.png` with jQuery function, if there is any.

Comment: @hey if that is true, then change it with php (or whatever your server is) when its outputting the js. otherwise just don't use `.` in your IDs

Comment: @hey `var selectorEscaped = 'bo.selecta.shamone'.replace(/\./g, '\\.');`

Answer (score 1):

A `.` character indicates the start of a class selector, so you need to escape it.

The CSS escape character, `\` is also an escape character in JS, so you need to escape it too.

```
$('.dfv\\.png').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the dot in the class name.

Try this:

```
$('.dfv\\.png').show();
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/9KYmx/1/

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.dfv\\.png').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in my use case, the class wasn't known till run time

simple regex replace worked fine

```
var selectorEscaped = 'bo.selecta.shamone'.replace(/\./g, '\\.');
```

to test:

```
$('body').append('<div class="bo.selecta.shamone"/>');
var selectorEscaped = 'bo.selecta.shamone'.replace(/\./g, '\\.');
$('.' + selectorEscaped )
```